# Meaning of "Algebra of all functions separates points on unit circle"

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $K$ be the unit circle in the complex plane, and let $\mathcal{A}$
> be the algebra of all functions of the form
> $$f(e^{i\theta})=\sum\limits^{N}_{n=0}c_ne^{tn\theta}\text{ ($\theta$
>  real)}$$ Then $\mathcal{A}$ separates points on $K$ and $\mathcal{A}$
> vanishes at no point of $K$, but nevertheless there are continuous
> functions on $K$ which are not in the uniform closure of
> $\mathcal{A}$.

Could anybody explain what this question means? Is there any specific math term of "algebra"? And I don't understand how we say it separates the unit circle. I'd appreciate any explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *algebra* is a vector space (or, more generally, a module) equipped with a multiplication that plays nicely with the vector space operations. In this case, the vector space operations are all pointwise, and the multiplication is just pointwise multiplication of functions.

A set $S$ of functions $X \to Y$ *separates points* of $X$ if for all $a,b \in X$, there is some $f \in S$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$.

What the question is getting at is that all of the conditions of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem are necessary. That theorem says (in one of its forms):

> **Theorem**: If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ containing a non-zero constant function, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ if and only if it separates points on $X$.

Here, we have a compact Hausdorff space (the unit circle $K$) and a subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $C(K,\mathbb{R})$ which separates points, but $\mathcal{A}$ is not dense in $C(K,\mathbb{R})$. That is: the requirement for $\mathcal{A}$ to contain a non-zero constant is necessary for the theorem to hold.

Answer (score 1):

Being an algebra means that if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two such functions and if $\alpha$ is a scalar, then $f_1+f_2$, $f_1\cdot f_2$ and $\alpha f_1$ all belong to it also.

And asserting that this set separates the points means that if $x,y\in K$ and $x\ne y$, then there's some function $f$ from that set such that $f(x)\ne f(y)$.